# Does none of the usual MySQL admin/query tools support extra long table and column comments?

Tags: mysql, comments, compatibility

according to the reference (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html), MySQL 5.5 now supports table and column comments of extended length (2048 or 1024 chars, respectively), which I appreciate highly.
However, none of my MySQL apps (Workbench, HeidiSQL, SqlYog) seems to be able to apply that new rule, neither for newly created table nor for table alterations. I'm especially disappointed by Workbench since I assumed it was developed by the MySQL team.

What are your experiences? What do you think about it? Do you know of some programs/versions capable of handling this new feature?

Best,
Steve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I raised the issue in the HeidiSQL forum and now the feature got implemented in a recent build! ;)